# Parse semicolon delimited string where the values can have a semicolon

Tags: javascript, string, delimiter

I have a string that is provided from an external API (unconnected ping from a Minecraft Bedrock server), that looks like the following format:

`Edition (MCPE or MCEE);MOTD line 1;Protocol Version;Version Name;Player Count;Max Player Count;Server Unique ID;MOTD line 2;Game mode;Game mode (numeric);Port (IPv4);Port (IPv6)`

I would simply just do `string.split(';')` to get each of the values between the semicolon delimiter, but the problem is that the `MOTD line 1` and `MOTD line 2` values can have a `;` within them, as part of the value. Here is an example of the format above without semicolons in the values themselves:

`MCPE;Dedicated Server;390;1.14.60;0;10;13253860892328930865;Bedrock level;Survival;1;19132;19133;`

... and here is the example above with semicolons in the values for the MOTD line 1 and 2:

`MCPE;MOTD A;B;C;390;1.14.60;0;10;13253860892328930865;Bedrock level a; b; c;Survival;1;19132;19133;`

As you can probably guess, simply splitting the string by the delimiter is not going to work. The MOTD lines 1/2 are provided by the server owner and can contain just about any character. Only the MOTD values can contain semicolons in the values.

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't get any help within any programming server on Discord. I've attempted using RegEx to parse the MOTD lines up until the next `;number` but I'm not experienced enough to do that. [Here is the link](https://wiki.vg/Raknet_Protocol#Unconnected_Ping) from where I got this string from.

Comment: So what *is* known? When there are the problem semicolons, will it always start with MOTD? If so, is there a particular format to the values that will come after?

Comment: You cannot parse them if you don't have a way to distinguish them. Normally you should have an escape sequence for this.

Comment: @slappy Yes, the MOTD lines 1/2 will sometimes be problematic. The values are provided by the user and can contain any character discussed in the `string` data type in the protocol page: https://wiki.vg/Raknet_Protocol#Data_types

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that's what I'm thinking. The server doesn't escape it in any way. I'll just have to find someone else's example and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Here is updated answer based on new recent comment.

Try

```
x.split(';').reduce((prev, current) => { 
    if (/^\d/.test(current) || prev.length === 0 || !prev[prev.length - 1].startsWith('MOTD')) prev.push(current);
    else prev[prev.length - 1] += ';' + current;
    return prev;
}, []);
```

Comment: The value for `MOTD line 1` can allow any character, a whitespace does not have to follow the semicolon. I will update the example to cover this.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding, the entire MOTD value can be literally any value. I just provided an example that happened to include the same word as the description.